# How to displace the origin of the Y axis on a polar Mschart?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mschart

Im working on a polar chart with mschart, and I need to make this "hole" on the middle of the chart. I mean, i need the "0" of the Y axis not to be on the center. I saw this plot  somewhere on stackoverflow. It´s exactly what i need, how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a radar plot that look like the provided example

```
// disable grid a long X
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;

// set Y axis
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -20;  // creates the 'hole' by setting min Y
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = 20; // so the major grid does not fill the 'hole'
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 5;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
And do you know how did he managed to make the tick marks  match the intervals, and also start from 0 at that position?

Comment: Setup `AxisY.MajorTickMark` identically to `AxisY.MajorGrid` to get matching ticks.