# Polar Plot with mschart C#

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I'm currently working on a project, in which I need to create a Polar Plot with dynamically generated data. I've managed to create a somewhat decent polar plot, but have not been able to create what is needed.
[This is my Polar Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTpvs.png)

this is the code I used to set the offset in the middle:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;


        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -20;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = 15;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 5;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;

    }
```

I found some help here: [How to displace the origin of the Y axis on a polar Mschart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083881/how-to-displace-the-origin-of-the-y-axis-on-a-polar-mschart)

I got a example on how I'm trying to get the polar:
[The finished example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHRXu.png)

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: Somewhat, I'm tying to place the integers in the middle.

Comment: Meaning what? going to the center of the chart or sitting at the middle of the axis?

Comment: [I mean like the '1, 2, 3, 4' in side the inner circle. PictureLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHRXu.png)

Comment: These seem to be x-axis labels. On a Polar chart MSChart will not let you move the axis nor use a secondary axis. So only workarounds are possible: Either overlay with a second chartarea or drawstring the labels. Both is really tricky and may not be worth the trouble..

Comment: Thanks! I know that these might have been obvious, but I'm still learning. So I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can make an axis start from anywhere but its minimum.

(The linked post only makes the labels start from a different value.)

So we'll have to help with a little bit of owner-drawing.

A few short references:

```
var ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
var ax = ca.AxisX;
var ay = ca.AxisY;
```

Now let's hide the y-axis:

```
ay.LineWidth = 0;
```

To draw the portion of the axis from the interval offset to the maximum we simply code the `PostPaint` event:

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    // add references..
    ..
    // then use values to calulate pixel coordinates..
    int py1 = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(ay.Minimum + ay.IntervalOffset);
    int py2 = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(ay.Maximum);
    int px  = (int)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(ax.Maximum -  ax.Minimum);

    // blue to make it stand out
    e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, px, py1, px, py2);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Of course finding the right values for `Interval`, `IntervalOffset`, `Minimum` and `Maximum` is all up to you..

**Update:** If you want to have a full set of shortened x-axis gridlines you could do a lot of math or use a graphics transform. As usual the latter is so much easier..:

```
Graphics g = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics;
int pyc = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(ay.Minimum);  // y-center
for (int i = 0; i < 360 / ax.Interval; i++)
{
    g.TranslateTransform(px, pyc);
    g.RotateTransform((float)(i * ax.Interval));
    g.TranslateTransform(-px, -pyc);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.colorOfYourChoice, px, py1, px, py2);
    g.ResetTransform();
}
```

After setting `ax.Interval = 30;` we get this result:

[image]

Comment: is there anyway to set the interval for the X-axis? so that there is lines drawn from the first circle to the last, at every angle placed?

Comment: OBS! I know that I can set the X-axis interval, but it changes the angle interval. what I was wondering is if I can change the length of the lines that are usually drawn from the center to the edge, at every angle.

Comment: I updatd the answer to include a full set of x-axis gridlines.

Comment: Thanks! but why/how did you get the g?

Comment: Whoops, it is the e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.

Comment: ahh. Thanks! :)